# How can I use if function in excel to count unique numbers which are not greater than given time duration

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have bunch of transaction data containing date, time, ID

like this:

```
  DATE         TIME           ID 

7/6/2015     9:30:22       0266731550    
7/6/2015     9:33:19       0266731550    
7/6/2015     10:31:38      0266731550
```

then I want to count how many transactions **per day** that are **unique** (can be identified by the ID) but **the time no longer than 5 minutes**.

For example, there are 3 same IDs , for the 2 first ID `0266731550` counted as 1 because its time gap with the previous ID `0266731550` is not more than 5 minutes (`9:33:19-9:30:22 < 5mins`).

Different with the third ID `0266731550`, it's counted as 1 because its time gap with the previous ID `0266731550` is more than 5 minutes (`10:31:38-9:33:19 > 5mins`).

ps: I'm using ms. excel 2010

Comment: Can you add a fourth column that calculates the time difference between a transaction and the previous transaction?  Also - What if you have four transactions spaced three minutes apart from each other?  How many "unique" transactions should that count as?

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your answer. It looks like impossible for me to calculate the time difference between a transaction and the previous transaction manually because there are lots of data. Or do you know the formula to calculate the time difference which only refer to the duplicate IDs? - If that transaction had the same ID, I count that as 1

Comment: Are all of the entries in chronological order?  Are the IDs intermixed or are all entries for the same ID grouped together?  Do the times cross midnight?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not adverse to using VBA, I can get back with more detailed code later, but in pseudo-ish code:

```
Dim array(1, 1) As Long

For i = 1 To Len(table)

    ' if value is already in the array, skip this part. if not, redim the array and store the value.
    If Not Match(Cells(1, i), array) <> 0 Then
        ReDim array(1, i)
        array(1, i) = Cells(1, i).Value
    End If

    ' write the time intervals for comparison
    Dim intervals(2, 1)
    ' iterate over the column where timestamps are and write all of them to array, checking with array(1, i) to make sure the ID is correct. redim as required.
    ' sort the array and measure for 5min intervals.
    ' keep a unique-values variable that you increment every time a satisfactory interval is found.
Next i
```

You can push these values to the worksheet, to a file or into an msgbox.

Comment: Hi vsoraas, thank you for your answer. But I think I don't familiar with VBA. Could you please explain where should I put that code?

Comment: That isn't complete code, so it wouldn't do any good - it was just a concept to gauge interest :) I can write it out for you, but it'll take me a while (I'm not at my workstation for a while yet).